# My 404 page isn't working

Tags: html, github, http-status-code-404

My 404 page isn't working. The code in my *.htaccess* file is

> ErrorDocument 404 /error.html

Even though I have this code (it is supposed to send you to the 404 page), I still get the 404 GitHub page.

[image]

Here are my github repo files:

- https://github.com/BrundinNet/BrundinNet.github.io/blob/master/.htaccess
- https://github.com/BrundinNet/BrundinNet.github.io/blob/master/error.html

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a GitHub help site (see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site/)), and it's summarised below:

1. Make a new HTML file at the root level called `404.html`
2. Add the following [YAML front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) code (all this means is it goes at the top of the file and it's a different language):

   `--
   permalink: /404.html
   --`
3. Add your content from `error.html`!

This should hopefully help, great question! I'm also working on a GH pages site (cgs-jack-bashford.github.io) and this is a great way to research things- check Stack!

Comment: Could you specify which file name ;)

Comment: Just changed it - better?

Comment: Would you mind uprooting me? I would appreciate the reputation gain greatly!

Comment: I would, although I need 15 reputation to do that. (I have 13) :)

Comment: I'll vote up you then!

Comment: Yay, you now have 18 reputation!